# Make functions private inside another function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects

Im sitting with oo Javascript and I wondering how to make a function private inside another function... my function "render()" have a lot of functions inside and that render function loads at the end of the page... but how do I write them? I have my example and what Ive done so far... can someone help me understand it?

Those are my functions:

```js
 (function($) {
    'use strict';
    session.page.pending = true; 
    var Product = finance.entre.Model.extend({ 
            type: 'Product',
            render: function() {
              
 //here should all this functions inside render: function() (like  addEventHandlers: and populatepage:) become private
              
    addEventHandlers: function(){     
       $(document).on('change',':input[name=PR_Type]', function(event) {
                    var $target = $(event.target);
                    product.updateObjectTypes($target.val());
                    product.updateHideWhen();
                });
                $(document).on('focus', ':input[name=DocUNID]', function(){
                    this.select();
                });
            },
            populatePage: function() {
                console.log('populatePage');
               if (session.user.type == 'Internal') {
                    $('.external').remove();
                   dbService.dbLookup('main', 'vwInsurances', 2, null).done(function(data){
                        console.log('lookup done');
                        $('select[name=PR_Insurance]').setOptions(data, true);
                    });
                }
    });
              
              
    $.when(session, $.ready).then(function(){
            var product = new Product(undefined, {id: session.page.id});
            product.fetch().always(function() {
            product.render();
            session.page.render.resolve();
        });
    });
```

So I tried something like this:

```js
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    session.page.pending = true; // delay translation until page rendered
    var Product = finance.entre.Model.extend({ // override passed options with below
            type: 'Product',
            render: function() {
                
                $(document).on('change',':input[name=PR_Type]', function(event) {
                    var $target = $(event.target);
                    product.updateObjectTypes($target.val());
                    product.updateHideWhen();
                });
                $(document).on('focus', ':input[name=DocUNID]', function(){
                    this.select();
                });
              
                ...
```

I just deleted the name declaration of the function inside "render()" is that right? or should I declare something like -i dont know- var instance = this; and call "this" in some specials places?

Thank you very much to everyone who take his time to check the code can explain a little bit :) !!

Comment: what do you mean make them private? a function defined within a function is only visible within that function unless you specifically make that function visible by using globals or some other method ... so, really, if they are not private it's because you've done something to make them public - simple answer, don't do that thing

Comment: this has nothing to do with oop ...

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i start to understand better now!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var Product = finance.entre.Model.extend((function (){

    function private1() {}
    function private2() {}

    return {
         type: 'Product',
         render: function() {
                private1();
                private2();
         }
    };
}()));
```

Comment: thank you @cske! Im make in it this way now and seems to work better